# Getting undefined for this.props.data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I keep getting undefined for this.props.data when I have passed it from by setting this.state this.props.data from last component.

Here is the jobOffer component which properly passes data and render:

```
const JobOffer = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Navigation],

  getInitialState: function() {
    console.log(this.props.data);
    return {
        listing: this.props.data
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    AppStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },


    _onChange : function(){
      this.setState({listingDetail:this.state.listing});
    },


  handleClick: function () {
    this.transitionTo('/listing/' + this.state.listing.id );
  },


  render: function () {
      var data = this.state.listing;
      var employmentType;
      switch(data.employment_type) {
        case 'F':
            employmentType = 'Full Time';
            break;
        case 'P':
            employmentType = 'Part Time';
            break;
        case 'H':
            employmentType = 'Hourly';
            break;
        default:
            employmentType = 'Unknown';
      }
      return (
        <a onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <img style={{width: 50+'px', height: 50+'px'}} src="images/job1.jpg" alt="" className="img-circle" />
            <div className="title">
                <h5>{data.job_title}</h5>
                <p>{data.Business.business_name}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="data">
                <div ><i>Posted 1 Day Ago</i></div>
                <div className="city"><i className="fa fa-map-marker"></i>{data.Business.business_city}</div>
                <div className="type full-time"><i className="fa fa-clock-o"></i>{employmentType}</div>
                <div className="sallary"><i className="fa fa-dollar"></i>{data.job_compensation}</div>
            </div>
        </a>

      );
    },

});


module.exports = JobOffer;
```

You can see that I am passing listingDetail when _onChange. Here is the jobDetails component that is is giving the undefined error.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactBootstrap = require('react-bootstrap');
var Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
var Modal = ReactBootstrap.Modal;
var AppActions = require('../actions/app-actions');
var AppStore = require('../stores/app-store');
var Navigation = require('react-router').Navigation;
var _ = require('lodash');

var JobOffer = require('./JobOffer');


// Our custom component is managing whether the Modal is visible
const ListingDetail = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Navigation],

  getInitialState: function() {
    console.log(this.props.data);
    return {
        ListingDetail: this.props.data
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    AppStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },


  _onChange : function(){

  },


  handleClick: function () {
    this.transitionTo('/listing/apply/' + this.state.ListingDetail.id );
  },


  render: function () {
      var data = this.state.ListingDetail

      return (
            <img style={{width: 200+'px', height: 200+'px'}} src="images/job1.jpg" alt="" className="img-circle" />
            <div className="title">
                <h5>{data.job_title}</h5>
                <p>{data.Business.business_name}</p>
            </div>
                <div className="city"><i className="fa fa-map-marker"></i>{data.Business.business_city}</div>
                <div className="type full-time"><i className="fa fa-clock-o"></i>{employmentType}</div>
                <div className="sallary"><i className="fa fa-dollar"></i>{data.job_compensation}</div>

            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-8">
                  <h3></h3>

                  <article>
                    <h2>Job Details</h2>
                    <p>{data.job_description}</p>

                  </article>
                </div>

      );
    },

});


module.exports = ListingDetail;
```

Any idea?

Comment: `this._onChange.bind(this)`

Comment: where? In componentDidMount in JobOffer?

Comment: Everywhere. PS: it worth trying before you ask next time

Comment: when adding .bind(this) got : Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call. See JobOffer
ListingDetail.js:18 undefined
ListingDetail.js:47 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'job_title' of undefined

Comment: So? It's a different problem with your code already.

Comment: `var data = this.state.listing;` --- why do you think `this.state.listing` is defined?

Comment: in JobOffer? Its defined because it's passed from a JobListings componente `const JobsListing = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Navigation],

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        listings: []
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    AppStore.addListingChangeListener(this._onChange);
    AppStore.getListings(true);
  },


  _onChange : function(){
    this.setState({listings:AppStore.getListings()});
  },`
which is working. Only thing not working is ListingDetails

Comment: `this.setState({listingDetail:this.state.listing});` --- here you replace the state with an object that does not have `listing` property. So, why do you think `this.state.listing` should be defined?

Comment: Well what im trying to do is pass the data _onChange of the listing

Comment: Yep, but the new state's structure is different from old. :-S Not sure what your current problem is and why it confuses you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82878/discussion-between-rahul2001-and-zerkms).

Comment: As far as I know, `setState` does not replace the current state object with the one provided as an argument, but rather shallowly merges the two.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that neither `JobOffer` nor `ListingDetail` is being rendered anywhere. Which component is going to render which?

The `this.props` property of any component is going to contain any properties that were passed to the component at the point it was rendered (or rather "mounted", in React's component lifecycle terminology). It's not meant to be mutated during the component's lifespan, so you can view them as "initialization" values. The `this.state` property of a component on the other hand should contain properties that do change throughout the component's lifecycle, and each time you change it by using `this.setState()` the component will be re-rendered (unless you prevent a re-render in the `this.shouldComponentUpdate` method) to reflect the new state.

So, `this.props` contains any values that you passed as "attributes" when mounting the component. If you use JSX it could look something like this:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <DetailsListing id={123} job_title="React Dev" />;
    }
});
```

In this case, `DetailsListing`'s `this.props.id` is 123 and `this.props.job_title` is "React Dev" as expected.

You seem to confuse the difference between *state* and *props* by returning props as an initial state. Props should be props and state should be state, not intermixed (this might be opinionated, but I think it's definitely mandated by the React principles). Either way, `this.props` will only contain the values that you passed it when rendering/mounting.